# CPU 100% on uWSGI master getting killed, server not taking requests

Tags: uwsgi

I am facing this problem where my uWSGI error logs show "UAAAAAAH my master disconnected: i will kill myself !!!".

This has happened twice in 2 weeks and surfaces only when we deploy code, which does a uwsgi --reload /tmp/X.pid. uWSGI is controlled by supervisor but this step just reloads uWSGI, no errors are shown on our Jenkins box but munin shows that CPU usage hits 100%, high disk IO and disk latency and requests to this box are timing out. I have to manually go in and restart uWSGI and that has fixed the issue on both occassions.

I would appreciate if someone can please share ideas in how to handle this issue.

uWSGI version: 2.0

supervisor: 3.0b1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I am running in to a open issue with this uWSGI.

[uWSGI open issues](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/296)

Comment: Apparently the current workaround is to pass in --die-on-term.